# R shiny tabset title modify font size

Tags: css, r, shiny

I've got an R shiny webpage (v.0.3) with a bunch of tabPanel's inside a tabsetPanel in the mainPanel. The collection of tabs take a lot of space at the top of the page, so I am looking for ways to shrink them.

I would like to change the font size of the tabPanel titles so that they don't take so much space, but it seems the first parameter, the title, only accepts literals, and not HTML().

Any ideas?

Example:

```
# Default
tabPanel("I like turtles")
# doesnt work
tabPanel(HTML("I like turtles"))
# or
tabPanel(HTML("<span style='font-size:10px'>I like turtles</span>)")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use css:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Hello Shiny!"),
  sidebarPanel(),
  mainPanel(
    tags$head(
      tags$style(type='text/css', 
                 ".nav-tabs {font-size: 10px} ")),    
      tabsetPanel(tabPanel("Plot"))
    )
  )
)
```